# Python function name finder not working

Tags: python

Trying to make a function to find names of python functions in a file 
for a python class I have no idea why it's only returning one comma that I add in between the function names

```
def pythonanalysis(s):
    pythonlen = str(s.count("\n"))
    functionname = ''
    funcdoc = s
    counter = 0
    while funcdoc.find("def") != -1:
        function = funcdoc.find("def")
        funcdoc = funcdoc[function + 4:funcdoc.find("(")]
        functionname += funcdoc[:funcdoc.find("(")] + ", "
        counter += 1
        print(functionname)
    forlen = str(s.count("for"))
    iflen = str(s.count("if"))
    whilelen = str(s.count("while"))
    authnum = s.find('__author__ =')
    author = s[authnum + 14:]
    authname = author[:author.find('\'')]

    return "There are " + pythonlen + " lines in this file \n\
    There are "+ str(counter) + " functions in this document named: " + functionname + "\n\
    There are " + forlen+" for loops and " + iflen + " if loops and " + whilelen + " while loops\n\
    The author is " + authname
```

Comment: The code you posted by itself will fail immediately when it refers to `funcdoc`, can you a) provide a complete example, and b) what it *does* do (print an error, not give the expected output, etc)?

Comment: @NickT Just added the rest, and it doesn't fail its just the only thing it returns for the function finder is the comma I add

Comment: You should give a better error description than `not working`.  That alone is a reason many will vote to close. What exactly isn't working and if you could also provide some simple input and out exhibiting your issue that would put your question in good stead.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function = funcdoc.find("def")
    funcdoc = funcdoc[function + 4:funcdoc.find("(")]
```

The "(" that you find could quite possibly be BEFORE the "def", which would result in an empty string here!  Even if you did find the "(" that's just after the function name, you discard the entirety of the file after that point, so you could never find more than one function.  Hint: the `str.find()` method takes an optional second parameter that specifies the starting point of the search.